# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I'm getting the error messages:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future <dynamic>`
_LocationScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> 
(package:clima/screens/location_screen.dart:71:32) 
<asynchronous suspension>
```

The line being pinpointed is inside this:

```
FlatButton(
   onPressed: () async {
     var weatherData = await weather.getLocationWeather();
     updateUI(weatherData); //<==it's this line
                    },
```

`weather.getLocationWeather()` returns a variable of type `Future<dynamic>.` It's JSON and, evaluating it in the debugger, it's the expected JSON. The `upDateUI()` method begins

```
  void updateUI(Future<dynamic> weatherDataFuture) async {
    final weatherData = await weatherDataFuture;
```

and then goes on to parse the resulting weatherData. It's called earlier in the program and works as expected. I'm sure the issue is connected to my never ending but still continuing battle to understand asynchronous programming :-)

Comment: The weather.getLocationWeather() value is "_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>" and seem "updateUI(Future)" returns the same that "weather.getLocationWeather()"

Comment: @NorbertoMartínAfonso -- Thanks for responding! I am not sure I understand totally. I understand weather.getLocationWeather() apparently returns type "_InternalLinkedHashMap<String,dynamic>". But updateUI() is void; it does not return anything(?).

Comment: Try my answer I was edited and returns map values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await weather.getLocationWeather()` gets the future returned by `getLocationWeather` and waits for it to complete to a value. That value is a map.

You then call `updateUI` with that map value, even though it expects a futuure. The variable is typed as `dynamic`, so you get no static warnings, just a run-time error.

```
   onPressed: () async {
     var weatherData = await weather.getLocationWeather();
     updateUI(weatherData); //<==it's this line
```

Try removing the `await`. Then `weatherData` will be a `Future<dynamic>`, which is exactly the type expected by `updateUI`. (You can then also remove the `async` from the function).

Comment: Your suggestion fixed the issue, so thank you! I understood it perfectly, and it has the added bonus of helping me understand better the suggestions of the two other folks who were kind enough to respond.

Comment: I think I got confused because toward the end of (this post) [https://medium.com/flutter-community/futures-async-await-threading-in-flutter-baeeab1c1fe3] the author wrote "...whenever you choose to await a future the function must be marked as async and therefore all who call it must be awaited and they must be marked as async..."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```dart
final weatherData;
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> weatherDataFuture async{
  return weather.getLocationWeather();
}

FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
  weatherDataFuture.then((value){
   weatherData=value.values;
 });
} 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your edited response (and welcome to SO :-) ... I am struggling a bit to understand your code, probably because I am a beginner. For me, `weatherDataFuture` is just a parameter name. If I used it as is in the `onPressed()` method I'm sure I would get an error about an undeclared variable.  Perhaps I also should have clarified in my original post how `weatherData` is a different variable in the `onPressed()` and `updateUI()` methods. That was bad variable naming on my part.

Comment: Than you very much. I think you want to give data from some database to a final variable. Then you need a Future to wait for the data, and when you press FlatButton the data will send to that final variable. In the code when you use Future.then((value)), you are waiting for data (value), and when data exists "then" you can set the  "Map.values" to  final variable weatherData.

Answer (score 0):

The return value from getting the data needs to be casted. I’d recommend looking into the JSON tutorials in the flutter documentation.

```dart
    FlatButton(
       onPressed: () async {
         var weatherData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(await weather.getLocationWeather());
         updateUI(weatherData); //<==it's this line
    },
```

```dart
void updateUI(Map<String, dynamic> weatherData) async {
    ...
```

===== edit based on comments =====

```dart
FlatButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      var weatherData = SynchronousFuture(Map<String, dynamic>.from(await weather.getLocationWeather()));
      updateUI(weatherData); //<==it's this line
},
```

```dart
void updateUI(Future<Map<String, dynamic>> weatherData) async {
    ...
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Changing the weatherData declaration will produce an error in the next line telling me the argument type 'List' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'Future'.

Comment: It probably needs to be cast to a `Map`, not a `List`

Comment: Ah sorry, that's what I get for trying to answer a question on my phone. So now that the future is resolved before handing it off to `updateUI` you can update `updateUI` so that it takes a `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: Yes, that change makes sense and is appropriate (as was the case for my question you kindly answered last week :-) I'm tempted, in fact, to tell you to leave it for future people coming here. For me, what I didn't say in my original post, is that updateUI() is called elsewhere (without issues), so the change you suggest ends up breaking other code.

Comment: Sounds like some refactoring might be in order :) however you can wrap your casted `Map` in a `Future` or a `SynchronousFuture` for the time being.